# Android direct download subscription eSIM (provisioning profile)

Tags: android, provisioning, e-sim

I am working on an Android application that will install the eSIM directly through our app. like provisioning the eSIM profile without going to the wizard cellular settings.

So, I read all the documentation in google docs for a section of [esim provisioning through a carrier app (my app)](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/esim-overview#carrier-privileges), but I don't know how to work and apply the access rule file (ARF) that will grants the permission to my app to use the EuiccManager class, and this method is always returns false `hasCarrierPrivileges`, I have the LPA and others information related to eSIM profile?!

Any help or guide or sample?

Answer (score 1):

The app signature is presented in the metadata that is returned from the SM-DP+ during the SIM profile installation procedure prior to actually downloading and installing the SIM profile data.

Though this privilege elevation features the same mechanism/rules as used for the UICC Carrier Privileges it is delivered differently - in the metadata as part of the installation procedure because the installation procedure itself depends on it. Whereas UICC Carrier Privileges expects to find the app signature in a SIM file that is part of a SIM profile that is already installed:

> "[The eUICC OS and SM-DP+ must support a proprietary tag BF76 in the
> profile metadata](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/esim-overview#carrier-privileges). The tag content should be the same carrier
> privilege rules as returned by the access rule applet (ARA) defined in
> UICC Carrier Privileges"

Now once the SIM profile is installed it isn't clear whether or not the carrier app privileges persist. If not then the downloaded profile could perhaps itself contain an ARA applet and provide UICC Carrier Privileges persistently.

I've written [a more detailed article on this feature here](https://medium.com/@mode51/esim-rsp-android-app-privilege-elevation-for-write-embedded-subscriptions-5a3abc053a54).